# Is there a package include Phi and Crame v?

Tags: r, correlation

With different data, we need to use different correlation function ,such as `pearson`,`phi`, `Cramér's V`.

Correlation is a basic statistic method.
Is there a package include `pearson`,`phi`, `Cramér's V` and other correlation function?

I googled but cannot find a solid and completed answer.

Comment: stats::cor() include the most common methods for numeric variables e.g. pearson, kendall, etc. I don't think any base/stats R function will include all the possible variations.

Comment: `questionr` has a Cramér's V calculation, though I  wouldn't load a whole package to calculate it -- you could write a function and verify it works properly in less time than would take to load the package and read the documentation to call the function in it. As for why something like Cramer's V isn't in vanilla R, an econometrician would as easily ask why something as "standard" as Jarque-Bera tests weren't there, while a medical statistician would wonder why something as "standard" as Bland-Altman plots aren't there. What looks "standard" depends on vantage point.

Comment: `assocstats()`from `vcd`,`cramer.v`from`questionr`,and `lsr`,`rcompanion`,so many functions to calculate crame V.Why so many choices to a simple function? Is there a best one? That's the pain when I use R.We just need all-in-one-best statistic tool.I think R should forbidden duplicated function!!

Comment: `vcd` is a useful package for working with categorical data.  I didn't realize there was a function with Cramer's V in there.  I would use that one.  The package has other useful functions that are worth investigating.

Comment: [assocstats](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vcd/versions/1.4-3/topics/assocstats)

Comment: @SalMangiafico,I revised this question,pls reopen it.

Comment: @kittygirl , I didn't vote to close the question.  But I suspect the reason it was closed is that it [still] is written as a question about  R functions. Questions about software are off topic on this site.  I think the heart of the question is actually about statistics, and so could have been left open.

Comment: If you have questions about programming you should post them on stackoverflow. In case of questions about R go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

Answer (score 3):

So, for continuous variable `R` has the function `cor()` even within that you need to define a `method`. Because you apply different types of correlations for different types of data. Take phi and Cramer's V : they're both chi-sq based, but phi is used for 2x2 matrices and Cramer's V for more than 2x2. Tetrachoric is more nuanced where you're finding similarity in continuous variables based on ordinal variables.

As for why they exist in different packages: R is open sourced, people contribute what they feel the need to.

Comment: agree but hate the duplicate function name in vary packages,that's bad idea.Maybe it's better to  use python instead of r.

Comment: 'Programming language A does not have feature X from programming language B' does not directly imply 'Programming language A is worse than programming language B'

Comment: @kittygirl you may appreciate package:imports and/or package:strict in R. BTW, Python packages duplicate tons of function names (only hidden because of conservative namespacing), nevermind the rampant abuse of the bit shift operator. Just sayin'.